# what name function php I need to use to read setting file permissions on windows?

Tags: php, permissions, settings

did it is possible to read the setting file permissions(Octal Notation/Symbolic Notation) using php function?
thanks.

Comment: The "See also" sections in the manual for PHP functions are there for a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fileperms()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)